# What causes warning " Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" in this case?

Tags: php, foreach, flickr, invalid-argument

I cant grasp what in this case is causing the invalid argument warning. I have seen that there is plenty of information about the warning itself, but as I am new (started today with php) I cant figure it out even if I have read many questions about this at the forum.
The error occurs in the for-each loop. Please be very specific in your answers as I am learning.

```
<?php
function GetWeather($city){
    $content = file_get_contents("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" . $city . "&units=metric");

    $data = json_decode($content, true);

    $placeinfo = '<span id="City">' . $data['name'] . ", " . $data['sys']['country'] . '</span>'
            .   "<br />"
            .   '<span id="Conditions">' . $data['weather']['0']['main'] . '</span>'
            .   "<br />"
            .   '<span id="Temperature">'  . ceil($data['main']['temp']) . " C</span>"
            .   "<br />";
    return $data ['weather']['0']['main'];

}

Function GetFlickr($city, $conditions)
{    
    $apikey = '';
    $apisecret = ''; 

    $flickrurl = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&tags=" . $city . "," . $conditions . "&sort=relevance&format=json&api_key=" .$apikey;
    $flickrurl .= 'per_page = 1'; 
    $result = file_get_contents($flickrurl);
    $jason = substr($result,  strlen("JasonFlickrApi(")-1);
    $flickrjson = json_decode($jason, true);       

    var_dump($flickrjson);        

    foreach ($flickrjson['photos']['photo'] as $photo) {
        $url = "http://farm" . $photo['farm'] . ".static.flickr.com/" . $photo['server'] . "/" . $photo['id'] . "_" . $photo['secret'] . "_m.jpg";
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $url; ?> " alt=" <?php echo $photo ['title']; ?>">
    <?php
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that $flickrjson['photos']['photo'] is an array or an iterable item ?

Comment: what does `var_dump($flickrjson);` outputs?

Answer (score 3):

Change...

```
foreach ($flickrjson['photos']['photo'] as $photo) {
```

to...

```
foreach ($flickrjson['photos'] as $photo) {
```

**Explanation**
`foreach` loops through arrays and the above looks to me like you're trying to loop a singular object rather than an array.

Basically though `invalid argument supplied foreach()` means you've passed something that isn't an array or an object e.g. a string, integer, or null.

Comment: Hi, exchanged to 2 the code you supplied but did not see any effect on the warning. You mentioned that the problem is that I passed something that is not a array. When I try var flickrjson dump; I get a Null. Can you see why this happens?

Comment: You need to figure out where your code is not performing as expected. I suggest you dump out `$result` and `$jason` (which should be `$json` really). Also try removing the spaces in your `'per_page = 1'` string.

Answer (score 0):

**foreach** will generates this warning if the given argument is not an **Array** or an **Object**

You must always do this check before calling to foreach()

```
if (is_array ($flickrjson['photos']['photo'])) {
    foreach ($flickrjson['photos']['photo'] as $photo) {
    // ...
    }
}else {
    // a good/must practice to log warning/error/fatal 
    // log.warn("invalid argument");
}
```